line 41: field enabled not found in type aggregation.Config when start loki
when I am using this command to start loki:
loki --config.file=./config.yml

show error like this:
failed parsing config: ./config.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 41: field enabled not found in type aggregation.Config. Use `-config.expand-env=true` flag if you want to expand environment variables in your config file

then I tried like this:
root@iZhp33cq6mvrjo8mzatgrmZ:/etc/loki# loki --config.file=./config.yml --config.expand-env=true
failed parsing config: ./config.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 41: field enabled not found in type aggregation.Config

this is the config.yml:
root@iZhp33cq6mvrjo8mzatgrmZ:/etc/loki# cat config.yml 
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096
  log_level: debug
  grpc_server_max_concurrent_streams: 1000

common:
  instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

query_range:
  results_cache:
    cache:
      embedded_cache:
        enabled: true
        max_size_mb: 100

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: tsdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v13
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

pattern_ingester:
  enabled: true
  metric_aggregation:
    enabled: true
    loki_address: localhost:3100

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093

frontend:
  encoding: protobuf

# By default, Loki will send anonymous, but uniquely-identifiable usage and configuration
# analytics to Grafana Labs. These statistics are sent to https://stats.grafana.org/
#
# Statistics help us better understand how Loki is used, and they show us performance
# levels for most users. This helps us prioritize features and documentation.
# For more information on what's sent, look at
# https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/pkg/analytics/stats.go
# Refer to the buildReport method to see what goes into a report.
#
# If you would like to disable reporting, uncomment the following lines:
#analytics:
#  reporting_enabled: false

does anyone facing the same issue? This is the loki version:
root@iZhp33cq6mvrjo8mzatgrmZ:/etc/loki# loki --version
loki, version 3.3.0 (branch: k227, revision: 19bbc448)
  build user:       root@bbfd3492a6b4
  build date:       2024-11-19T11:25:17Z
  go version:       go1.23.1
  platform:         linux/amd64
  tags:             netgo

I tried to print the ascii charactor and seems no special charactor:
root@iZhp33cq6mvrjo8mzatgrmZ:~# cd /etc/loki
root@iZhp33cq6mvrjo8mzatgrmZ:/etc/loki# awk 'NR>40 && NR < 43' config.yml | od -c
0000000                   e   n   a   b   l   e   d   :       t   r   u
0000020   e  \n                   l   o   k   i   _   a   d   d   r   e
0000040   s   s   :       l   o   c   a   l   h   o   s   t   :   3   1
0000060   0   0  \n
0000063


I don't know loki. Would you have a link to the documentation of the pattern_ingester configuration? Is there an enabled field there?

It looks like the supported parameters are described here Supported contents and default values of loki.yaml - I don't see mention of enabled under metric_aggregation

The error message points to the fact that enabled is not a valid field of the metric_aggregation subsection of the pattern_ingester section.
The supported structure of the loki config.yml file, and the various default values of each section, are described on the Grafana web site.
The documentation for the limits_config block suggest that one may want to use
limits_config:
    metric_aggregation_enabled: true

... to enable metric aggregation.  This is the full documentation about that section:
# Enable metric aggregation. When enabled, pushed streams will be sampled for
# bytes and count, and these metric will be written back into Loki as a special
# __aggregated_metric__ stream, which can be queried for faster histogram
# queries.
# CLI flag: -limits.metric-aggregation-enabled
[metric_aggregation_enabled: <boolean> | default = false]

Note: I am not a Grafana user, and I'm only quoting what I found in the documentation.
